# "Nach einer halben Stunde . . . wurde haltgemacht"

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, passive

The question is on the highlighted sentence in this excerpt from *Der Verschollene* (*Amerika*) by Franz Kafka.

> Aber fast alle Unzufriedenheit mit dem Reiten hörte auf, wenn Mack kam. Der lange Mann wurde weggeschickt, und bald hörte man in dem noch immer halbdunklen Saal nichts anderes als die Hufe der galoppierenden Pferde und man sah kaum etwas anderes als Macks erhobenen Arm, mit dem er Karl ein Kommando gab. **Nach einer halben Stunde solchen wie Schlaf vergehenden Vergnügens wurde haltgemacht.** Mack war in großer Eile, verabschiedete sich von Karl, klopfte ihm manchmal auf die Wange, wenn er mit seinem Reiten besonders zufrieden gewesen war, und verschwand, ohne vor großer Eile mit Karl auch nur gemeinsam durch die Tür hinauszugehen.

Is *wurde haltgemacht* in the passive voice?

If yes, why is it OK when *haltmachen* is intransitive?

**BACKGROUND**

First, here's what is not confusing me.  I know that:

- *Nach einer halben Stunde solchen wie Schlaf vergehenden Vergnügens* is an adverbial.  For the purposes of my question, we can simplify the sentence to

  > Nach einer halben Stunde wurde haltgemacht.
- German can sometimes dispense with an express subject as when

  > Es ist mir so wunderbar

  becomes

  > Mir ist so wunderbar.

The problem arises for me because according to [this](http://www.wordreference.com/deen/haltmachen) or [this](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/haltmachen) dictionary entry, *haltmachen* is an intransitive verb.

I can think of two possible answers.

1. *Haltmachen* is a special case.  It is made of *halt* and *machen.*  Suppose we rewrote the sentence by separating those components:

   > Nach einer halben Stunde wurde Halt gemacht

   That's well formed.  *Halt* is subject, and *wurde gemacht* in the passive voice.  This peculiarity of *haltmachen* allows *wurde haltgemacht.*
2. Any otherwise suitable intransitive verb can replace *haltmachen* to give us e.g.:

   > <strike>Nach einer halben Stunde wurde geregnet.</strike>

Or maybe I am way off base and *wurde* is not even the passive auxiliary.

I would like both an explanation of the syntax and some sample sentences of the same form, i.e. those made of:

> An adverbial + *wurde* + the perfect participle of an intransitive verb.

Comment: *Nach einer halben Stunde wurde geregnet* is no valid German sentence.

Comment: But *Nach einer halben Stunde wurde **be**regnet.* is. Wacky German!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling *haltmachen* or *Halt machen* (alternative form) intransitive is a bit of a misconception. It's rather a transitive verb that brings its own (and only possible) object. Together with this object ("Halt") it can very well form a passive.

> Halt wurde gemacht

The passive form of *haltmachen* needs to be impersonate as there is no subject otherwise:

> Es wurde haltgemacht

So your assumption (1) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is correct, there is nothing special here:

> Nach einer halben Stunde wurde gerastet.

Consider also:

> Nach einer halben Stunde wurde gegessen.

Of course, *essen* can be used transitively, but it is not in this case, and it is of no importance.

Comment: Thank you. (a) What would be *wurde* in *wurde gerasted*? I know that *werden* can be a passive or future auxiliary or the main verb *become*; but none of these seem to fit. (Of course I may simply have to accept *wurde* + perfect participle as a special form, which was my option 2.) (b) What would be *wurde* in *wurde gegessen*? I could only see it as *became eaten*, i.e. a passive that does not specify what was eaten. (Again it might be a special form meaning *some eating took place*.) (c) Is *Nach einer halben Stunde wurde geregnet* also OK?